Time-independence dependent on time-function
I am having trouble understanding time-functions in Schwarzschild spacetime when one coordinate is null. By definition, a function $f$ is called time-function if its gradient $\nabla f$ is timelike past-pointing. Consider Schwarzschild spacetime in Schwarzschild coordinates
$$g = - V(r) \ dt^2 + V(r)^{-1} \ dr^2 \quad , \qquad V(r) = 1 - \frac{2m}{r}$$
(neglecting the angular parts as they are not relevant here). In Schwarzschild coordinates in the region $\{ r > 2m \}$ the $t$-coordinate is a time-function, whereas in the region $\{ r < 2m \}$ the $r$-coordinate is a time-function.

QUESTION 1:
If I were to calculate the time-independent solutions to some PDE on Schwarzschild spacetime, e.g. $\nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu} \phi = 0$, then would time-independence mean in this case "independence of the time-function coordinate"? In other words, would time-independence mean $\nabla_t \phi = 0$ in the exterior region and $\nabla_r \phi = 0$ in the interior region?

In Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates however,
$$g = - V(r) \ dv^2 + 2 \ dv \ dr$$
one finds that $g(\nabla v, \nabla v) = 0$ in both regions. But as $g(\nabla r, \nabla r) > 0$ in the exterior region, both $v$ and $r$ are not time-functions. Nevertheless, along any timelike geodesic the coordinate $v$ is strictly increasing.

QUESTION 2:
Would time-independence in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates in the exterior region $\{ r > 2m \}$ then mean $\nabla_v \phi = 0$? Since $v$ is no time-function, I would find this odd. On the other hand, since $v$ is strictly increasing along any timelike geodesic, and so I could accept it. Then again, in the interior region $\{ r < 2m \}$ we ALSO have $g(\nabla r, \nabla r) < 0$, and so both $v$ and $r$ could be viewed as a time-function. Do we then have $\nabla_v \phi = 0$ or rather $\nabla_r \phi = 0$ for time-independence there?

